# How to replace a list of words to a new string?

Tags: javascript

Hello I am writing a script to replace some strings into an array called text which looks like this:

```
var text = document.getElementById("texto").value;
```

The words that I want to replace are stored in an array called:
colorWords:

```
var colorWords = Object.keys(filtered)
```

I would like to create an array called: tagText that would contain a new array called tagText with some strings replaced.

```
tagText=[];
```

In order to achieve this I tried:

```
for (i = 0; i < colorWords.length; i++) { 
    tagText.push(text.replace(/colorWords[i]/g, "<p><font color=\"red\">TEXT</font></p>"));
}
console.log(tagText)
```

But I failed with this approach since I get:

```
[""RBD|X|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGWO.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTH…X3|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXC.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"↵", ""RBD|X|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGWO.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTH…X3|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXC.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"↵", ""RBD|X|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGWO.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTH…X3|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXC.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"↵", ""RBD|X|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGWO.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTH…X3|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXC.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"↵", ""RBD|X|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGWO.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTH…X3|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXC.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"↵", ""RBD|X|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGWO.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTH…X3|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXC.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"↵", ""RBD|X|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGWO.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTH…X3|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXC.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"↵", ""RBD|X|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGWO.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTH…X3|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXC.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"↵", ""RBD|X|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGWO.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTH…X3|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXC.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTH
```

Which is wrong since it is not replacing the words contained in the array callde colorWords to the new string, I would like to appreciate any suggestion to achieve this.
My complete code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"><script src="./code33_files/lodash.js"></script> 
</head><body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<textarea cols="150" rows="15" id="texto">"RBD|X|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGWO.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGX4.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"
"RBD|X3|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGX6.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGX8.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa2"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXA.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa2"
"RBD|X3|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXC.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"
</textarea>
<script>
var text = document.getElementById("texto").value;
var splitWords = text.split(/[["\|~]/);
var removeArray  = _.remove(splitWords, function (word) {return word !== '' && word !== ' ' && word !== '\n'});
var dict = removeArray.reduce(function(p,c) {
    if (p[c] === undefined) {
        p[c] = 1;
    } else {
        p[c]++;
    }
    return p;
},{});
var filtered = Object.keys(dict).reduce(function (filtered, key) {
    if (dict[key] > 1) filtered[key] = dict[key];
    return filtered;
}, {});
var colorWords = Object.keys(filtered)
console.log(colorWords)


tagText=[];

for (i = 0; i < colorWords.length; i++) { 
    tagText.push(text.replace(/colorWords[i]/g, "<p><font color=\"red\">TEXT</font></p>"));
}
console.log(tagText)


</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Note that in your regexp `/colorWords[i]/` what you are doing is to search that  string `colorWordsi`. If you want to search the exact word then you have to replace it with shomething like `RegExp(colorWords[i])`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: I tried with that approach but I got the same result.